# 404 Not Found The request could not be mapped to any database

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Last few days I have been very tired to figure out this issue, and I also reinstalled ORDS few times, but I can't resolved this issue, can please help me to figure out.
I am using apache tomcat 7.0.77

```
[root@ip-xxx.xx.xx.xxx ords\]# mkdir ORDS-config
[root@ip-xxx.xx.xx.xxx ords\]# java -jar ords.war configdir ORDS-config/
May 01, 2017 9:41:11 AM oracle.dbtools.cmdline.ModifyConfigDir execute
INFO: Set config.dir to ORDS-config/ in: /u01/app/ords/ords.war
[root@ip-xxx.xx.xx.xxx ords\]# vim params/ords_params.properties
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@ip-xxx.xx.xx.xxx ords\]# java -jar ords.war
Enter the database password for ORDS_PUBLIC_USER:
Confirm password:
Please login with SYSDBA privileges to verify Oracle REST Data Services schema.

Enter the username with SYSDBA privileges to verify the installation \[SYS\]:
Enter the database password for SYS:
Confirm password:
Enter 1 if you want to use PL/SQL Gateway or 2 to skip this step.
If using Oracle Application Express or migrating from mod_plsql then you must enter 1 \[1\]:
Enter the database password for APEX_PUBLIC_USER:
Confirm password:
Enter 1 to specify passwords for Application Express RESTful Services database users (APEX_LISTENER, APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER) or 2 to skip this step \[1\]:
Enter the database password for APEX_LISTENER:
Confirm password:
Enter the database password for APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER:
Confirm password:
May 01, 2017 9:43:04 AM oracle.dbtools.common.config.file.ConfigurationFilesBase update
INFO: Updated configurations: defaults, apex, apex_pu, apex_al, apex_rt
Installing Oracle REST Data Services version 3.0.6.176.08.46
... Log file written to /u01/app/ords/logs/ords_install_core_2017-05-01_094304_00364.log
... Verified database prerequisites
... Created Oracle REST Data Services schema
... Created Oracle REST Data Services proxy user
... Granted privileges to Oracle REST Data Services
... Created Oracle REST Data Services database objects
... Log file written to /u01/app/ords/logs/ords_install_datamodel_2017-05-01_094320_00325.log
Completed installation for Oracle REST Data Services version 3.0.6.176.08.46. Elapsed time: 00:00:17.36

Enter 1 if you wish to start in standalone mode or 2 to exit \[1\]:2
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

[image: img]

Comment: If you are using multitenant architecture database(12c or greater), then while installing ords put database service name ORCLPDB instead of ORCL.

Answer (score 0):

404 is what you'd expect there - nothing's mapped to that URI.

Your install was a success, ORDS is running.

So if you publish a RESTful service in your HR schema, and aliased HR as 'HumanR', then you'd go to http:...8080/ords/HumanR/module/template/

But until you create a service, there's nothing for ORDS to serve up to you, so you get the 404.

Comment: If you're trying to get ORDS to serve up APEX for your database on the URL, then need to know if you're running ORDS in an app server like Tomcat or Glassfish

Comment: I have faced same issue, using tomcat - how can I map something to the URI? I am moving from embedded pl/sql gateway to ords..I got to the same screenshot now.